# Cant parse date to D3 line graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to create a line graph like below fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/wRDXt/2/

Here the date is used as `new Date(2013, 17, 1)`.

I have json contents as follows,

```
[{
    "_id": "bb68d8a2-8778-4c85-8616-ed1e96a61ea6",
    "FLAG": "public",
    "STATUS": "active",
    "DESCRIPTION": "df",
    "DATE_TIME": "04-10-2016 16:39:39",
    "TOKEN": "bge2jb",
    "LAST_UPDATED": "Tue Oct 04 16:39:39 IST 2016"
},
{
    "_id": "556ae8ad-7291-4303-a9e4-618a82694600",
    "FLAG": "public",
    "STATUS": "active",
    "DESCRIPTION": "d",
    "DATE_TIME": "04-10-2016 16:52:20",
    "TOKEN": "16l4jal",
    "LAST_UPDATED": "Tue Oct 04 16:52:20 IST 2016"
},
{
    "_id": "98db36ba-392d-4df2-ac6c-820eaf582a11",
    "FLAG": "public",
    "STATUS": "active",
    "DESCRIPTION": "uyk",
    "DATE_TIME": "07-10-2016 12:13:10",
    "TOKEN": "dfl5ja",
    "LAST_UPDATED": "Fri Oct 07 12:13:10 IST 2016"
}]
```

My date format, which came from api call is like `07-10-2016 12:13:10` or `Fri Oct 07 12:13:10 IST 2016`.

If I pass this date, I am getting following error in console,

```
Uncaught TypeError: minDate.getDate is not a function
```

How do I pass my date to this and get the graph.

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/wRDXt/190/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` in your `dataset` is not a date-object, but a string. Therefore it does not have a `getDate()`-function and you get the error you get.

To fix this, right after you have declared your dataset, loop through all entries in the dataset and redefine `date` by parsing the `date`-string:

```
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").parse(d.date);
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wRDXt/204/

[Reference for `d3.time.format`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md)

Comment: Now its accepting date but the graph is not proper.

Comment: Great, sorry for the mistake. it works like charm. Is it possible to pass the `LAST_UPDATED` key value to date?

Comment: Yes, you can also parse that. However i am not sure if it is possible to parse the timezone (IST). But `d3.time.format('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S IST %Y').parse(LAST_UPDATED)` will parse `LAST_UPDATED` (But instead of parsing it as IST, it will parse it as your local time.

Comment: Thanks Cleared, I have a query here, my date is 4/10/2016 and value is 2. But in graph it shows in 3/10/2016. I know the minDate is -1. How to get dot on top of 4/10/2016 instead of 3/10/2016.